# SocketIO callback from client to server doesn't work (null object instead)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm facing a weird problem with SocketIO, on the server-side i emit() this :

```
$s.sockets.emit(scope, {some: datas}, 

        function(feedback) {

             console.log('received callback');

        }

 );
```

And on the client-side I do this :

```
 this.Socket.on(handler, function (datas, callback) {

      callback('test');

 }
```

I'm waiting for the client to send a `callback('test')` the server will receive. Then it would output a simple `console.log('received callback')`

The client effectively receive the server request but on the client-side the callback type is `null` (object) instead of `function` ... If I remove the `function()` on the server side and don't wait for a callback the type on the client-side will be `undefined` which means that when the server expect a callback the `function` is somehow transmitted but transformed in an object (?)

Is it a bug ? Am I doing something wrong here ? Really weird ...

One more detail : i'm currently using **SocketIO 0.9.16**

Thanks people ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I didn't find any solution on getting a callback through `emit()` functionality. So I made a "trick" which is a parallel working solution :

When I `emit()` something that will involve a `callback()` on the server-side, I generate a key through a function and send the datas adding a `{ callback : key }` at the end of my datas object.

I also generate a `socket.on(key, function(datas) { callback(datas); socket.removeListener(key); }` which will be an equivalent of a classic callback in the system at the end.

This will be understood by the front which will `emit(key, datas...)` in response. The server will receive everything, do the stuff, and remove the listener.

Works like a charm but **a bit complicated** to make at first. Would've been nice if it worked directly with **SocketIO** ...

**If someone got stuck, I hope this helps :)**